How can I turn the touchscreen off alongside the screen?
When I close my laptop (GPD Win MAX 2) and turn off the builtin display in favour of an external one, the touchscreen is still running. This is not particularly useful, since I can't see what I'm tapping on. And when I close the lid it becomes actively harmful, because it incorrectly registers inputs while closed.
How can I disable the touchscreen when the screen itself is disabled?

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Wayland)
Kernel: 6.8.0-36-generic
APU: AMD Ryzen 7 8840U with Radeon 780M
RAM: 64 GiB
Disk Capacity: 2 TB

